# Selenium Radio buttons clicking, but not selecting

Tags: java, selenium, radio-button

I am currently using Selenium to try automate the filling of a form online when I ran into a bug that I haven't seen before. There are a series of radio buttons that equate to more or less true or false statements. They all appear to be working fine EXCEPT for the very first one, where it will indicate that it was clicked, but will not change states to "selected" (This can be observed here)
[image: Before the automated script][image: After automated script] 
--------------- As you can see, the options that were clicked display with a blue background, however the first selection didn't change. I am using the following code of:

```
driver.findElement(radioButtonValue ? locator1 : locator2).click;
```

To select between the two options for each individual group of radio buttons. The locators are of the button itself, not the group. The radio buttons are not hidden or read only, and can be clicked perfectly fine when done manually. I am really at a loss for what could be causing this. The HTML of the trouble button is:

```html
 <TD>Is this an Expert Transportation Account? </TD><!-- // vsm 107926 --><!-- // -->
    <TD><INPUT id=transportationFlgTrueId class=changed onclick=getSegmentBrokerBranch(this); value=true type=radio name=transpFlg jQuery16202104382506976572="13">Yes </TD>
    <TD><INPUT id=transportationFlgFalseId onclick=getSegmentBrokerBranch(this); value=false CHECKED type=radio name=transpFlg jQuery16202104382506976572="14">No </TD>
```

Any information or ideas of where to go would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use method isselected with if condition and then try to select that radio button.

Comment: What is `(radioButtonValue ? locator1 : locator2)` suppose to be? Have a read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @SiKing the idea is that it is a ternary statement with the radioButtonValue defined as a boolean, and locator1 and locator2 By.id variables which represent either clicking on true or false.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `driver.findElement(By.id(radioButtonValue ? locator1 : locator2)).click;` then?

Comment: The variables locator1 and locator2 are By variables, which means they are defined previously in the class such as `By locator1 = By.id("some_position")`. Regardless, this is not the point of failure for the code.